# Enumerated list in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins

Does anybody know plugin for Vim that allows making enumerated lists with items and subitems (with indent for subitems). If I delete the item, then number of other items should be changed. I could not find such plugin. May be somebody cad do it just using Vim commands?

Comment: Could you illustrate what you are looking for on an example maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for an [outliner](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=outliner&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search)? Or for a [TODO manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=todo&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search)? Or for [something else](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=utility&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search)?